# Adding implict soap header to axis1.4 client java

Tags: java, web-services, axis, soap-client

i am trying to call a webservice using axis1.4 client and java7 , i can add Auth header using soap ui but when i try it through the code i get UnAthurized 401 response from server.
main problem is the security header is not defined in wsdl file. so i expoerted soap project and find out some headers like:

```
<con:credentials>
                    <con:username>sarmayeh_gsb</con:username>
                    <con:password>Sarmayeh@gsb123</con:password>
                    <con:domain>estelamwebservice.nocservices.org/iws/Estelam</con:domain>
                    <con:selectedAuthProfile>Basic</con:selectedAuthProfile>
                    <con:addedBasicAuthenticationTypes>Basic</con:addedBasicAuthenticationTypes>
                    <con:authType>Global HTTP Settings</con:authType>
                </con:credentials>
```

how can i add this in my code?

i tried something like

```
EstelamLocator wsLocator = new EstelamLocator();
        logger.info("creating locateor...");
        EstelamPort ws = wsLocator.getEstelamPort(new URL("http://10.0.233.254/sabteahval/proxy/SabteAhvalPS?wsdl"));
        
        //add SOAP header for authentication
        SOAPHeaderElement authentication = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://est","Authentication");
       
        SOAPHeaderElement user = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://est","User", service_user);
        SOAPHeaderElement password = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://est","Password", service_pass);
        
        authentication.addChild(user);
        authentication.addChild(password);
        Estelam3TRequest re= new Estelam3TRequest();
        re.setBirthDate("13750427");
        re.setBirthDate("0019317859");
        logger.info("creat authentication...");
       ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub)ws).setHeader(authentication);
        ws.getEstelam3T("Bksr","Bk@Sr-0513","36571","915DE0DEAD1",re);
```

but the error still goes on.
any help would be apricciated.

Comment: please remove the real username and password and use fake one

Answer (score 0):

just import org.apache.axis.client.Stub and javax.xml.rpc then set username and password.

```
   EstelamLocator wsLocator = new EstelamLocator();
    logger.info("creating locateor...");
    
    EstelamPort ws = wsLocator.getEstelamPort(new URL("http://****/sabteahval/proxy/SabteAhvalPS?wsdl"));
    logger.info("creating EstelamPort...");

    Estelam3TRequest re= new Estelam3TRequest();
    re.setBirthDate("13750427");
    re.setNin("0019317859");

    ( (Stub) ws)._setProperty(Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY,service_user);
    ( (Stub) ws)._setProperty(Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,service_pass);

     logger.info("_setProperty on ws....");
     ws.getEstelam3T("Bksr","Bk@Sr-0513","36571","915DE0DEAD1",re);
     logger.info("return object....");
```